# Pass Information To Change Variable In Another ViewController When Segueing from UITableViewCell Tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

**BLUF**

I am attempting to pass information from a custom array to change a variable in another ViewController before I segue to it from a UITableViewCell Tap. My issue is that when I pass the information it does not stay stored. I have looked at similar questions, but they have not helped with this issue.

**Background**

I have created a message view controller similar to twitters using a UITableView (MessagingViewController)
[image]

When I click on the TableViewCell of a certain user post, I have another ViewController pop-up that has the user profile information. (ProfileSelect ViewController)

[image]

The variables I need to pass are stored in a custom array of type "Post" (a custom class I use to identify the position and data for each individual post).

```
var posts = [Post]()
```

Currently I get the profileSelect ViewController to show-up from a UITableViewCell Tap in the MessagingViewController using the following code. I pass the correct information from the "posts" array in MessagingViewController to the "set" method in profileSelect.

```
var profileSelect = profileSelect()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        profileSelect.set(post: posts[indexPath.row]) //pass information from MessagingViewController to set method in profileSelect
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileSelect", sender: self) //segues to ProfileSelect viewController
    }
```

This is the "set" method in the ProfileSelect Swift File.

```
weak var post:Post?
@IBOutlet weak var profileImageViewPic: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!

func set(post:Post) {
        self.post = post
        
        self.profileImageViewPic.image = nil
            ImageService.getImage(withURL: post.author.photoURL) { image, url in
                guard let _post = self.post else { return }
                if _post.author.photoURL.absoluteString == url.absoluteString {
                    self.profileImageViewPic.image = image
                } else {
                    //handle some error
                    print("Not the right image")
                }
            }//end of .downloadImage
            username.text = post.author.username
        }//end of func

    }
```

**Issue**

My issue is that when I pass the information before segueing, it does not stay stored when the profileSelect ViewController loads and I get an error that "profileImageViewPic" and "username" are nil.

[image]

**Question**

How can I pass that information from my MessagingViewController to ProfileSelect so that it is not nil and appears on the View Controller when it loads on the user screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `prepareForSegue` and send relevant data

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileSelect", sender:posts[indexPath.row])
```

---

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "profileSelect" { 
        let des = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileSelect  
        des.post = sender as! Post 
    }
}
```

and call `func set(post:Post) {`  inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: The only issue I have is that I never pass the array into the next ViewController. If I call "set" from "viewDidLoad", I never get the data from the Post Array I need from the other ViewController. What value do I pass into the "set" function?